# How to get the absolute path of eclipse project to use in .bat file?

Tags: java, batch-file, path, project

I want to get the absolute path of eclipse project to use in .bat file, but I have no idea.

THis is my .bat file:

```
@echo off
D:
cd **"D:\Workspaces4j\1st\web-parent\java-web"**
mvn tomcat:redeploy
pause
```

Please help me...thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need the the directory where pom.xml is located.

Right click on it in Eclipse, go to properties. You'll see the location. That would be what you need